# First time user of VS Code and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

First time user of Python in VS Code.  My import is not being recognized, i.e. random?

I have run my code in Anaconda Jupyter, so I know my code works.  It's a config issue.

```
import random
num = random.randint(1,2)
```

I expect no run-time errors.

But I get the following response in the console:

> ```
> num = random.randint(1,2)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> NameError: name 'random' is not defined
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you had not configured you python interpreter. You can select a Python interpreter by opening the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), start typing the Python: Select Interpreter command to search, then select the python interpreter you want to use for your current file.

If it still not working, you can refer to this VS Code [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response!